# Property 'value' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement' for Textarea - Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

Using Angular 4 (typescript), I have the below HTML code:

```
 <div *ngIf="dataService.selected_markers.length == 0" id="tsnPasteContainer">
      <form style="width: 100%; height: 100%">
        <textarea id="tsn_list" style="width: 100%; height: 100%" type="text" name="tsn_list" placeholder="e.g. 2001311,2425302,2153542,2435974"></textarea>
      </form>
    </div>
```

I am trying to get the data that the user is typing into the textarea using:

```
public parseTSNs(){
    let tsnString = document.getElementById("tsn_list").value;
    console.log("User inputted string: " + tsnString);
}
```

This function is called by a button.

The code is not compiling due to:

```
Property 'value' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'
```

This should be a simple function.  What am I doing wrong? W3schools "getting values from textarea" shows '.value' as the required function!

Comment: Please provide your whole relevant code. Based on the one from your question I succesfully made a working snippet https://jsfiddle.net/m1feyL6o/

Comment: Try to use `ngModel` or `#templateVariable`

Comment: Uh? Instead of using vanilla JS and `getElementById`, why don't you use Angular?... like, bind a model : `<textarea [(ngModel)]='textareaValue'></textarea>`

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You just have to assert that the type of your element is `HTMLTextAreaElement`. Because `document.getElementById` returns `HTMLElement` and not all html elements have the `value` property:

```
let tsnString = (document.getElementById("tsn_list") as HTMLTextAreaElement).value;
```

But seeing as you use Angular, you should probably be using data binding instead of querying the values yourself

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for.  Although I can (and will) just use data binding, I couldn't figure out why the vanilla JS code wasn't working when I've done this in the past without any issue.  I have never used "as" to assert something before - nor did I think it was necessary.  So out of curiosity, why did I have to do the "assert" to get this working in this scenario when @Ionut 's snippet worked perfectly without having to assert anything.

Comment: I just found this extract somewhere by Googling typescript compiling and HTMLElements: The "problem" is that typescript is typesafe. So the document.getElementById() returns the type HTMLElement which does not contain a value property. The subtype HTMLInputElement does however contain the value property.

Comment: @fila You are correct. lonut's code is plain JS. TypeScript provides additional type checking.

Answer (score 3):

I had faced a similar issue while setting the value of a cell in the table.

I was adding the data as follows:

```
document.getElementById("table_id").rows[0].cells[0].innerHTML = "data_to_be_added";
```

And I was getting the following error:

> error TS2339: Property 'rows' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'
>
> Property 'cells' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'

So I added the following tag and the ERROR got resolved.

```
(document.getElementById("table_id") as any).rows[0].cells[0].innerHTML = "data_to_be_added";
```

Here, you are expicitly changing the type of the variable as any.

Answer (score 0):

You should use: `[(ngModel)]='yourValue'` to bind data to  your controller. Textarea doesn't use `value` parameters.

Pleas read more information about HTML  tag and its attributes [hire](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_textarea.asp).

Comment: Oh, yes it does use value. It's just a bit different from other inputs, because it's between `<textarea></textarea>`.

Comment: Oh, yes it is. Is a multi-line text input. But I get the `[(ngModel)]='yourValue'`. That you are right.

Comment: In accordance with definition - true. But generally it's completely different than  input in support attributes.

Comment: In terms of `HTML` attributes, yes. But that does not mean you can't use `$('textarea').val()` or `document.getElementById('some_textarea_id').value` to get the **value** of it.

Comment: This is what my confusion was.  ".val()" and ".value()" were not compiling at all and your snippet extract above (which has worked for me in the past) worked fine.  But @Saravana 's code to make the assert as HTMLTextAreaElement worked perfectly...  I never thought that was necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Although it's not supposed to work like that, If you want to do it like this, first give your tag a reference with a `#` :

```
<div *ngIf="dataService.selected_markers.length == 0" id="tsnPasteContainer">
    <form style="width: 100%; height: 100%">
        <textarea #myTA style="width: 100%; height: 100%" type="text" name="tsn_list" placeholder="e.g. 2001311,2425302,2153542,2435974"></textarea>
    </form>
</div>
```

Then, in your component, import this :

```
import {ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
```

Declare a variable matching your reference :

```
@ViewChild('myTA') myTextArea: ElementRef;
```

In your method :

```
parseTSNs() {
    let el = this.myTextArea.nativeElement as HTMLElement;
    console.log(el.value);
}
```

Comment: I should have specified in the question that I was specifically looking for the reason why the vanilla JavaScript code wasn't working in Angular.  Although I agree entirely that this is the better method.

Comment: Well no, the best method is to use `ngModel`, the solution you want is just plain nasty. There's no need to use Angular if you use native JS !