# Angular: TS2339: Property 'before' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement' / 'HTMLTextAreaElement' / etc / etc

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript

**Goal**: I need to move a div (that has a mat-select dropdown) ABOVE a mat-card-title IF the user is on a mobile device. If they are NOT on a mobile device, then I want to keep it where it is (to the right of the mat-card-title)

What it looks like on non mobile devices:
[image]

**What I tried**:

- I tried using a basic condition with ngIf above, as well as below,
  but it makes the HTML look busy
- I also thought about media queries
  but examples always show something moving down, not up (if it is
  nested within something else)
- So then I tried using vanilla
  javascript, based on SO article: 
  [JavaScript moving element in the DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1363650/javascript-moving-element-in-the-dom)
- I've also looked at jQuery solutions, but I do not want to use jQuery

**Problem**:
I am getting error TS2339: Property 'before' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement' as well as 'HTMLTextAreaElement'

I have tried many variations of casting these variables, as per [Property 'value' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement' for Textarea - Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45028233/property-value-does-not-exist-on-type-htmlelement-for-textarea-angular)
But none of them work.

Not sure where to go from here?

**HTML**:

```
<div class="title-container">
    <mat-card-title id="signInTitle" class="text-center" i18n="@@MoVeSeLo_H1_1">
        Please Sign In
    </mat-card-title>
    <div id="langDropDown">
        <div *ngIf="(_lang_switch_controls)">
            <form [formGroup]="_siteForm">
                <mat-form-field class="language-field" appearance="outline">
                    <mat-select (selectionChange)="changeSite($event)" [value]="languages[i].value">
                        <mat-option *ngFor="let language of languages" [value]="language.value">
                            {{language.viewValue}}
                        </mat-option>
                    </mat-select>
                </mat-form-field>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**TypeScript**:

```
const signInTitle = <HTMLTextAreaElement>document.getElementById("signInTitle");
const langDropDown = <HTMLDivElement>document.getElementById("langDropDown");

var uagent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
    if (uagent.match(/iPad|iPhone|android/)) {
        signInTitle.before(langDropDown);
    }
```

Comment: Can you show your `tsconfig.json` and `tsconfig.app.json`?

Comment: @David I just added them

Comment: Which typescript version are you using?

Answer (score 1):

`HtmlElement` and the likes are defined in the typescript dom lib.

You need to use at least typescript 3.1.1 for these elements to implement `ChildNode` interface (which defines `before` method).

If you cannot update typescript, you can use `insertBefore`, or even the [Renderer2](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2) service from angular to manipulate DOM elements